# how to change specific value in one table based on coordinates listed in second table

Tags: dataframe, coordinates

I have two large csv files (*tables*).

First file look like this:

| row_name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Y | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Z | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Second file looks like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| a | X |
| a | Z |
| b | Y |
| c | X |
| c | Z |

I need to find value in the first file according the coordinates in the second file to change it to NA.

The result should look like this:

| row_name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | NA | 2 | NA |
| Y | 1 | NA | 3 |
| Z | NA | 2 | NA |

I have no experience with this kind of data manipulation, and I am lost for the moment. Can you help me?

I had a look on [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package in [r](/questions/tagged/r), but it did not help. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Are you open to other libraries/languages such as pandas/python ? Or you need an approach that uses R ?

Comment: I am opened to everything what will help me to solve it. I have just a little experience with python and pandas.

Comment: In your output, I think there is a mistake. First row, col c must be NA. Also, I posted a very basic solution with pandas, check it out ;)

Comment: You are right, sorry

Comment: No worries! Let me know if you're able to run a _python/pandas_ code (btw, you can use https://colab.research.google.com/ with`!pip install pandas`) and if my solution gives you or not the expected output.

Comment: I am runing pandas already, and getting closer :). I will let yoi know how it ended up for sure! THX

Answer (score 0):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can achieve what you want with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("tmp/f1.csv", index_col="row_name")
df2 = pd.read_csv("tmp/f2.csv", header=None)

out = df1.mask(pd.crosstab(df2[1], df2[0]).astype(bool), other="NA").reset_index()
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

  row_name   a   b   c
0        X  NA   2  NA
1        Y   1  NA   3
2        Z  NA   2  NA
```

Input used (*.csv files*) :

[image]

Comment: It is working! It looks so simple, I have to learn Pandas. Thank you very much for help and inspiration!